# Should there be a floor on votes?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, downvotes, voting, user-experience

Downvotes are useful, no doubt. They help users decide which questions and answers to read. They provide feedback to the person asking the question or posting an answer.

I'm not sure if overly large amounts of downvotes is beneficial to anybody.

For an example, this question, [Single login for multiple websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45588406/single-login-for-multiple-websites) (Don't downvote more than it already is please), got 10 downvotes.

I don't think the difference between -3 votes and -10 votes makes the difference in the decision to read the question (except out of morbid curiosity). I also don't think -10 votes is going to make the user significantly more likely to learn from the question than -3 votes.

So I don't see any real pros. I do see a con. This was a first post. The user didn't read the tour and didn't understand the site. I think they might be less discouraged if it was -3 votes rather than -10 votes. That way they may have become a productive contributing user.

The request is a substantial one, and it might be impractical for purely technical or UI/UX reasons. I think it's worth a discussion though. I propose having a total vote floor of -3 on questions, and maybe answers as well.

Comment: So then we should cap upvotes at +3 then, right?

Comment: What about 5 up votes and 10 down votes?  What do you do then?

Comment: As the rep goes down based on downvotes, they're being penalized for keeping bad content up for longer.  The quicker they edit their question into a good one, the less downvotes they'll get.  I don't see this as a bad thing.

Comment: @2EZ4RTZ No, you still need flag so that you can remove the comments constructively pointing out the problems with the question, because that's even worse than the downvotes.

Comment: @Servy great point. Lets rename them to "happiness flags" that way it is less negative

Comment: So, let's say that -12 question was capped at -3. What happens if it gets an upvote? Does it go to -2, or does it stay at -3 until it gets 9 more upvotes?

Comment: The irony of the downvotes is not lost on me. I see where you're all coming from.

Comment: @NathanOliver the total bottom would be -3, so it can have more than 3 downvotes, just the total score not below 3, is the suggestion at least.

Comment: @yannis that's a very good point. I didn't consider the existing questions.

Comment: @Goose, I don't think the downvotes are meant to be ironic.

Comment: @yivi I know, but even though it's not intended to be ironic, it is ironic that my question on questions with large amounts of downvotes has a large amount of downvotes.

Comment: It would certainly be discouraging for any OP whose question gets -3, but could be edited/added/improved, to find that they are lumped in with NullPointerException, 'i++ + ++i' and 'linked-list doesn't work, plz fix code URGENT' :((

Answer (score 5):

## No

You are removing the right to vote freely. Is there a difference?

YES. Question bans and other items like that rely on being able to get many downvotes. Believe me I know about question bans and downvotes :P